# python abstractmethods: appending a list to a subclass from abstractmethod

Tags: python, list, class, append, abstract-methods

I am trying to get familiar with abstract classes, but cannot figure out how I can append to an empty list in the class. this is how the directory i am working in looks like:

```
 my_dir
  |__data
  |    |__colors
  |    |    |__light_colors.csv
  |    |    |__dark_colors.csv
  |    |    |__cold_colors.json
  |    |__ages
  |__code
       |__data_reader.py
       |__config.py
```

in my config file i have:

```
import os

REPO_ROOT_DIRECTORY = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
colors_DATA_DIRECTORY = os.path.join(REPO_ROOT_DIRECTORY, "data")
```

and in my data_reader.py file i have the following code, which is an abstract class.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from config import colors_DATA_DIRECTORY
import os

class PathReader(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def read_data_type(self): pass
    
class colorReader(PathReader):
    def __init__(self):
        self.path_to_types = os.path.join(colors_DATA_DIRECTORY, 'colors')
        colors= []

    def read_data_type(self):
        for files in os.listdir(self.path_to_types):
            colors.append(os.path.join(self.path_to_types, files))

 g= colorReader()
 print(g.read_data_type())
```

however, it seems the list colors= [] is empty and ideally i would like to use this list in another abstract class so, i can check the extension of the files stored in the list, so this is how the code in data_reader.py continues.

```
class ExtensionReader(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def file_extension_reader(self): pass

class csvFileExtension(ExtensionReader): 
    def __init__(self, file_type: PathReader):
        self.file_type = file_type
    
    def file_extension_reader(self):
        for files in self.file_type:
        if files.split(".")[1] == 'csv':
            print(files)
```

but this is where i have no idea how i can make use of the colors =[] list to check the extension of the files that end in .csv

Comment: Do not edit your question to solve the issues with your code. If you have a new question, you should create a new question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with abstract classes. You forgot to make your `colors` variable an attribute of `self`:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from config import colors_DATA_DIRECTORY
import os

class PathReader(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def read_data_type(self): pass
    
class colorReader(PathReader):
    def __init__(self):
        self.path_to_types = os.path.join(colors_DATA_DIRECTORY, 'colors')
        self.colors= []

    def read_data_type(self):
        for files in os.listdir(self.path_to_types):
            self.colors.append(os.path.join(self.path_to_types, files))

 g= colorReader()
 print(g.read_data_type())
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have corrected the code, however the list is still empty. i think the append does not work

Comment: fyi `print(g.read_data_type()` will always print `None`, as the function returns nothing.

Comment: i actually realized that, but the funny thing is when i write print(self.colors) right after  self.colors = [], it says the list is empty.

Comment: @zarakolagar then there is an error in your `read_data_type` method. Consider making a new question about that.

Comment: thank you, i will. but i am not sure if there is an error in read_data_type as printing the files in the for loop, returns the three files in the directory